# Changes to a bound google sheet script not recognized

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet app with a bound script. I modified the script, did a save and ran the script. The original script runs, not the modified one. I've tried logging off, logging on, reloading, renaming, deleting and recreating, all to no avail. Testing or debugging also run the original code. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: can you give more information? like what is the "original" script and what is the modified. how are you running the script?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error. I modified the original script, then inadvertently concatenated the modified version to the original, instead of replacing the original. The result was that I had 2 occurrences of each function. Subsequent mods were made to the first occurrence of one of the functions, but the second occurrence was being executed. Thanks